# Does Visual Studio for Mac 2019 not work with mono-game along with pipeline?

Tags: c#, monogame, visual-studio-mac

I'm starting to use MonoGame and use a MacOS Mojave. I downloaded version 3.7.1 from the official website along with the standalone pipeline(*THOUGH I DOWNLOADED PIPELINE ONLY FOR ADDITIONAL TOOLS*).

After installation I opened VS 2019 and checked the project template and no new MonoGame template.

I thought that it should work right away? Do I need to download an older VS version?

Comment: I ran the 5 steps in this article to run MonoGame on VS4M 2019 [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://www.monogameextended.net/posts/getting-started-with-monogame-extended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work for now, but you cann use one of the those two work around:

1) If you already have VS2017 installed, you can copy the templates to the 2019 folder and they will appear in the laqunch.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\MonoGame 
to 
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\MonoGame
```

2) You can create it using the following commands:

```
dotnet new --install MonoGame.Templates.CSharp
dotnet new mgdesktopgl -o MyGame
```

Comment: I have installed Mono + MonoGame so it doesnt have `dotnet` command are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Not that I'm aware sadly, sorry!