# Why is it not displayed in visual studio when I installed monogame?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, monogame

I decided to install monogame to start making games)))

But when I installed monogame its project creation does not show up in visual studio 2019.

I have mac os 10.15.6, visual studio comunty for mac 2019 and I trying install monogame 3.7.1.

I have been rebooted my PC.

[image]

Can I do it: [image]

Comment: "Visual Studio 2019" is a completely different product from "Visual Studio for Mac 2019" (which is a rebadged Xamarin Studio).

Comment: Have you followed this page? https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_creating_a_new_project_vsm.html

Comment: @Dai That page isn't very good, as it's referring to an as-of-yet unreleased Monogame 3.8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Visual Studio for Mac 2019 not work with mono-game along with pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607671/does-visual-studio-for-mac-2019-not-work-with-mono-game-along-with-pipeline)

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: I redacted my ask)))